# How do I add users to a group in Confluence?

Tags: confluence

I am a confluence administrator and I am trying to set up permissions for a recently created space.

I added a new group (call it "my-group-admin") and gave it full access. I added that group to the space.

Now I am trying to add users to that group but every time I do so, it just fails silently. (The group admin screen returns showing the group with the message "No users found")

Any ideas why this might be happening or how best to add users to this group?

I am using version 5.5.4 of Confluence.

Comment: Are you using only Confluence or do you have some other atlassian-products? Maybe your users/groups are managed by your jira?

Comment: Hmm, lemme check that

Comment: Also, triple check that you're getting the user name right. It fails with no explanation if you misstyped and it didn't find the user

Comment: What is your Confluence version? 
There is a known issue with groups where if the group name has unusual characters or is not created correctly the group can not be used. If this happens, the only solution is to delete the group and create it again. Suggest typing the group name in - copy/paste can cause issues. Make sure the group name doesn't have a space at the start or end when using Add Group .

Comment: Seb you were right. It was being managed by Jira.

Comment: So it would be a good idea to close that question ... so that others don't try to answer it.

Comment: mliebelt - Is that how it works? Do we close a question when an answer was accepted, so that others don't try to answer it?